# I am getting a "SSL_connect wrong version number (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)" when trying to connect to elasticache endpoint from rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl, redis, openssl

I have a redis cluster in elasticache which is has cluster mode enabled. I follow the steps to test the connection that are explained here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/GettingStarted.ConnectToCacheNode.html and the connection between my ec2 instance and the redis cluster is working fine. The problem comes when I try to connect a user to a channel of the rails app. When the connection is being created this exception is raised

#<Thread:0x0000ffff7152d840 /usr/local/bundle/gems/actioncable-7.0.7/lib/action_cable/subscription_adapter/redis.rb:160 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
/usr/local/bundle/gems/redis-4.8.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:264:in `connect_nonblock': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=172.31.6.145:6379 state=error: wrong version number (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

this is what I have in my config/cable

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  ssl: true
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") %>
  channel_prefix: my_app_backend_development
```

in my .env I have

`REDIS_URL=rediss://my-app-staging-web-sockets-cluster.lvng.clustercfg.use2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379` 
this are the version of the gems that I have

```
gem list | grep openssl
# openssl (default: 3.1.0)

gem list | grep redis
# redis (4.8.1)
```

when I run

```
openssl version
# OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.9 30 May 2023)
```

in the elasticache service I am using the redis 7.0.7 version and the type of the nodes is cache.t2.micro

I have tried updating the openssl gem and the redis gem, but that didn't work

Comment: You likely access the wrong redis endpoint, i.e. the one which does not have transport encryption (TLS) enabled. Based on the documentation you refer to the TLS enabled endpoint start with "master" - which I don't see in your rediss:// URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 'In-Transit Encryption' i.e. SSL enabled for your cluster, you need to use a different endpoint with `master` at the beginning.

As per docs:

> In-transit encryption not enabled
> clusterName.xxxxxx.nodeId.regionAndAz.cache.amazonaws.com:port
>
> ...
>
> In-transit encryption enabled
> master.clusterName.xxxxxx.regionAndAz.cache.amazonaws.com:port